# How to create a step line Chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create a step line chart as the below figure

[image: Step line chart]

I tried to search for this chart ,but can't find any reference for that.

I hope someone could help me :).

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to use the [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) package and try to repurpose the [scatter plot example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/scatter_plot_charts/comparison_points) into something you want. Otherwise, you will probably have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @Abion47 I found a lot reference for other charts except the step line one :( ,between thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_echarts 
It's `Webview` and `Javascript` base.
You can config chart with `option` string 
Step Line Chart example https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-step
code snippet

```
Container(
                child: Echarts(
                  option: '''
                   {
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['Step Start', 'Step Middle', 'Step End']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_echarts/flutter_echarts.dart';
import 'package:number_display/number_display.dart';

final display = createDisplay(decimal: 2);

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  List<Map<String, Object>> _data1 = [
    {'name': 'Please wait', 'value': 0}
  ];

  getData1() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));

    const dataObj = [
      {
        'name': 'Jan',
        'value': 8726.2453,
      },
      {
        'name': 'Feb',
        'value': 2445.2453,
      },
      {
        'name': 'Mar',
        'value': 6636.2400,
      },
      {
        'name': 'Apr',
        'value': 4774.2453,
      },
      {
        'name': 'May',
        'value': 1066.2453,
      },
      {
        'name': 'Jun',
        'value': 4576.9932,
      },
      {
        'name': 'Jul',
        'value': 8926.9823,
      }
    ];

    this.setState(() {
      this._data1 = dataObj;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    this.getData1();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Echarts Demon'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Echarts(
                  option: '''
                   {
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['Step Start', 'Step Middle', 'Step End']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Step Start',
            type: 'line',
            step: 'start',
            data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
        },
        {
            name: 'Step Middle',
            type: 'line',
            step: 'middle',
            data: [220, 282, 201, 234, 290, 430, 410]
        },
        {
            name: 'Step End',
            type: 'line',
            step: 'end',
            data: [450, 432, 401, 454, 590, 530, 510]
        }
    ]
}                  ''',
                  extraScript: '''
                    chart.on('click', (params) => {
                      if(params.componentType === 'series') {
                        Messager.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                          type: 'select',
                          payload: params.dataIndex,
                        }));
                      }
                    });
                  ''',
                  onMessage: (String message) {
                    Map<String, Object> messageAction = jsonDecode(message);
                    print(messageAction);
                    if (messageAction['type'] == 'select') {
                      final item = _data1[messageAction['payload']];
                      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text(item['name'].toString() +
                            ': ' +
                            display(item['value'])),
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                      ));
                    }
                  },
                ),
                width: 300,
                height: 250,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```